# How would Nietzsche argue against classical theism?

Tags: metaphysics, theology, nietzsche, aquinas, classical-theism

Completely out of curiosity, how would someone like Nietzsche, let's use him as an example, argue against Aquinas's metaphysical argument for classical theism. I can't seem to find any references in his works, so I thought it would be an interesting thought experiment to think about how Nietzsche would argue against someone like Thomas Aquinas. I'm excited to see your answers.

Comment: It promotes the idea that someone who pays more is above the rules?

Comment: Folks seem to be upvoting the question, so it can't be as bad as it seems.  But I agree, defensively putting a bounty on a question you know is weak to protect it from closure is inappropriate.

Comment: Nietzsche's argument against classical theism is "Look around.  How much damage has been done by this concept, versus how much good?  It was a beautiful idea -- several of them even.  We get the point, but it didn't work."  What more needs to be said?

Comment: I'd say Nietzsche saw power as deeper & more fundamental than rational thought, which is only given meaning by *serving* our will-to-power. It's subversive, & intentionally confrontational - he just stated that the power of the Christian ideas is already gone; God is dead. Sociologist of religion Durkheim got at the same matter I think less hyperbolically: religion as social glue, instead of as sets of truths. See https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/91010/what-are-some-philosophical-works-that-explore-constructing-meaning-in-life-from/91017#91017 Nietzsche sidestepped, basically.