Any works that go in depth on the psychological underpinnings of engaging in philosophical inquiry at all?
Any works that attack in a systematic way the fears and hopes etc. that lie under the person who engages in philosophy? For instance, I know that is very plausible to say that basically all religions (which can be considered primitive metaphysical systems) with doctrines of an afterlife, have been at least in part developed out of the religion-creators’ fear of the mystery of death and what it entails.

I don't think that 'engaging in philosophy' is the ground that religion attacks, but those who don't. Perhaps those who do (with more enquiring minds) are less susceptible.

This answer addresses your topic: 'What are some philosophical works that explore constructing meaning in life from an agnostic or atheist view?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/91010/what-are-some-philosophical-works-that-explore-constructing-meaning-in-life-from/91017#91017 Specifically by framing death-anxiety as arising with the shift from wanting a life to be meaningful as judged from within a person & day by say, to a lide that will have been meaningful, which can only be judged by those who remain & inherit

Rorty & Nietzsche are modern exemplars of the attempt to dissolve rather than solve the issues of philosophy, & that 'shewing the fly from the bottle as our goal. This article links them to other thinkers: 'Nāgārjuna, Nietzsche, and Rorty’s Strange Looping Trick' https://absoluteirony.wordpress.com/2014/09/17/nagarjuna-nietzsche-rorty-and-their-strange-looping-trick & to a task for philosophy I call creating 'epistemic elbow room', creating a framing for productive & meaningful discourse, rather than being stuck with contradictions & irreconcilable disagreements

People get involved in philosophy in many ways and for many reasons. Trying to find medical causes behind any human endeavor and reduce the involvement solely to that is nothing but a form of medicalization and is a misrepresentation both of those involved and the field itself.

Denial of Life
A Critique of Pessimism, Pathologization, and Structuralism in Ernest Becker’s The Denial of Death - by Daniel Podgorsky
https://thegemsbok.com/art-reviews-and-articles/denial-of-death-ernest-becker-criticism-critique-analysis/

I think that taking life seriously means something such as this: that whatever [one] does on this planet has to be done in the lived truth of the terror of creation, of the grotesque, of the rumble of panic underneath everything. Otherwise it is false. (283-284)


This is simply short-sighted; there is no mention here of people doing what they do on this planet in the lived truth of the calm or joy of creation, only the terror of creation. Reality is much more complex, multifarious, and elusive toward singular emotional definition than a portrait of it as straightforwardly terrifying will ever be able to show. Becker writes as though he is unaware of this gigantic pessimistic oversight in his argument.

Sigmund Freud wrote a book called Civilization and Its Discontents. The basic plan of this book is to argue that the newborn ego strives to become happy and remain so in this world. That is called psychological or motivational hedonism: all human actions are efforts to generate pleasure and avoid pain. Then Freud tries to explain why the individual ego often fails to become happy in the context of society. Freud argues that reality is inherently hostile to the ego; it threatens us with death and destruction from forces inside or outside the body; and biological nature is inherently aggressive. Socialization in early life often induces more pain than pleasure and the human body is made to persist such unpleasure in the social context. In essence Freud argues that humans are inherently unable to coordinate our respective desires to love and work in social groups in ways that satisfy the authentic hedonistic needs of every individual ego. Becker takes this idea much farther to argue that denial of death drives most of the individual efforts, religious customs, and cultural norms. Terror management theory argues that all human efforts are efforts to manage and avoid unconscious terror that threatens to become conscious.

One can wonder about the motivations for philosophical pessimism though.. Is it love of pain over pleasure, or an apologetic of every oppressive and exploitative social regime..?

@Nikos M. Baruch Spinoza describes affect (emotion) as a feeling of desire, pleasure, or pain accompanied by an idea of its cause. He describes desire as appetite accompanied by consciousness thereof. Freud maps biological impulses to the unconscious source of inner drives: aka the id. Freud says the id makes the ego strive to become happy in the world. Pessimism in hedonistic models is persistent pain that drives out optimistic pleasure. What causes pain to interfere with the drive for pleasure? Is it genetic predisposition, social pain in life or early life, fear of death, or an ego choice?
